# Having touble trying to execute PHP artisan serve in my linux ubuntu 20.04

Tags: php, linux, laravel-artisan

Tried to resolve this issue but unable to find a solution for this problem adding the error below, kindly help me find the solution.

> PHP Warning:  require(/home/faiez/Desktop/git_project/ebelong_repo/bootstrap/autoload.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/faiez/Desktop/git_project/ebelong_repo/artisan on line 16
> PHP Fatal error:  require(): Failed opening required '/home/faiez/Desktop/git_project/ebelong_repo/bootstrap/autoload.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/php') in /home/faiez/Desktop/git_project/ebelong_repo/artisan on line 16

Comment: Does the file bootstrap/autoload.php actually exist? If it doesn't that's the problem. If it's there and you still have problems you can check permissions... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30639174/how-to-set-up-file-permissions-for-laravel

Comment: yes autoload.php exists in the vendor folder,

Answer (score 0):

Probably you have dated artisan script.

1. Run `composer update` in console.
2. Go to framework repo (https://github.com/laravel/laravel) and look at artisan script (https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/8.x/artisan). It's for 8.x version. Find file of your version. Your file has to be the same as file in a repo.

Comment: tried this and now it is showing other errors

Comment: In Connection.php line 664:SQLSTATE[HY000] [2054] The server requested authentication method unknown to the client (SQL: select * from information_schema.tables where table_schema = ebelong_db and table_name = users)

Comment: In Exception.php line 18:SQLSTATE[HY000] [2054] The server requested authentication method unknown to the client

Comment: In PDOConnection.php line 40:SQLSTATE[HY000] [2054] The server requested authentication method unknown to the client
In PDOConnection.php line 40:PDO::__construct(): The server requested authentication method unknown to the client [caching_sha2_password]

Comment: Make sure you've got the right db configuration. https://laravel.com/docs/master/database#configuration Make sure your database exists. Also try to run `php artisan migrate`.